# Clear selected item on multiple radio group with onCheckedChangeListener

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I'm currently working on my college project. In the app, I have an activity with a fragment. The fragment contains a layout which has nested linear layouts with multiple customized radio buttons in it. I can't put one single radio group to enable the single selection for the buttons because of the linear layouts making it to not work as intended.

So what I did is I made a radio group for the 5 sections and for me to able to select only one item from all the buttons, I tried to use the clearCheck() to clear the selection on other radio groups programmatically.

**fragment_parking_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ParkingLayoutFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FACILITY"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Entrance/Exit"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#31a81c"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_slot_1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="bottom">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_stairs"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_5"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio_pwd"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radio_pwd"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </RadioGroup>
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radio"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is a part of the code in the fragment**

```
public class ParkingLayoutFragment extends Fragment {

RadioGroup radio_group_1, radio_group_2;
public ParkingLayoutFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parking_layout, container, false);

    radio_group_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_1);
    radio_group_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_2);

    radio_group_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            radio_group_2.clearCheck();

        }
    });
    radio_group_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            radio_group_1.clearCheck();
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
}
```

As you can see I have set an onCheckedChangeListener to the 2 radio group so when I select an item on the first radio group, the second radio group will be cleared out and vice versa. But when I run the app and tried to select an item the app just freezes and restarts to the main activity.

**Here is a part of the error in the logcat which looks like a loop**

```
at com.grawlix.parkingally.ParkingLayoutFragment$1.onCheckedChanged(ParkingLayoutFragment.java:39)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
    at com.grawlix.parkingally.ParkingLayoutFragment$2.onCheckedChanged(ParkingLayoutFragment.java:46)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
    at com.grawlix.parkingally.ParkingLayoutFragment$1.onCheckedChanged(ParkingLayoutFragment.java:39)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
    at com.grawlix.parkingally.ParkingLayoutFragment$2.onCheckedChanged(ParkingLayoutFragment.java:46)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)

read: unexpected EOF!
```

Hope anyone knows what's up with this. Any idea is appreciated and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, `rg` is your first radio group and `rg1` is second radio group, You will be currently facing OOM error with your code. `clearChecks()` will trigger `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` you need to check if view returned is null or not.

```
rg = findViewById(R.id.rg);
rg1 = findViewById(R.id.rg1);

rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener((radioGroup, i) -> {
    RadioButton rb = findViewById(i);
    if (rb != null && rb.isChecked()) {
        rg1.clearCheck();
    }
});


rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener((radioGroup, i) -> {
    RadioButton rb = findViewById(i);
    if (rb != null && rb.isChecked()) {
        rg.clearCheck();
    }
});
```

Comment: Already realized that it triggers again the on check listener and found a temporary solution but I tried yours and it's working as intended than mine. Thank you very much this helped a lot.